# What is the easiest way to initialize a std::vector with hardcoded elements?

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, std, stdvector

I can create an array and initialize it like this:

```
int a[] = {10, 20, 30};
```

How do I create a `std::vector` and initialize it similarly elegant?

The best way I know is:

```
std::vector<int> ints;

ints.push_back(10);
ints.push_back(20);
ints.push_back(30);
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: if you are not going to change the size of ints after initialization, consider using tr1 array.

Comment: @zr, you have me curious... if I needed fixed size, could I not use plain old arrays themselves? Looking at tr1 array right now...

Comment: `tr1::array` is useful because ordinary arrays don't provide the interface of STL containers

Comment: Changed the title to make this explicitly a C++03 question. It seemed easier than going through and fixing all the answers to make sense with the new standard C++.

Comment: This is called [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

Comment: Not exactly what is asked, but if you need to initialize the vector with just one value, you can use `vector::assign()` as well.

Comment: Just to say that `std::vector` lies in heap (it has a `new`) so, there is no performance profit from hardcoded elements. But if `push_back` are many, then a reallocation can take place which IS performance cost. Of course syntactically it is better to use the initialization list.

Answer (score 586, accepted):

One method would be to use the array to initialize the vector

```
static const int arr[] = {16,2,77,29};
vector<int> vec (arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) );
```

Comment: @Agnel It will work fine without `static` or `const`, however they both make it more explicit as to how it should be used and allow the compiler to make additional optimizations.

Comment: I didn't downvoate this, but I was tempted. Mainly because this saves you almost nothing over just using the initialized array in the first place. However, that's really C++'s fault, not yours.

Comment: Can you explain why you're using those parameters when defining the vec vector.

Comment: sizeof(array) is one of the few exceptions that allows to get the total size of elements of the array and NOT the arr pointer dimension. So basically he's using vector(pointer_to_first_element, pointer_to_first_element + size_in_bytes_of_the_whole_array / size_of_one_element) that is: vector(pointer_to_first_element, pointer_after_final_element). The type is already given with the <int>, so the vector knows how much is one element. Remember that iterators can be treated as pointers so you're basically using the vector(iterator begin, iterator end) constructor

Comment: Not only is this method easy and standalone without any extra requirements, but it can also be made forwards-compatible with C++0x and their container initialization lists with the help of a macro, which eases syntax and portability a lot. +1.

Comment: It seems that if I use static const string attr[]={"abc", "def","ghi"} that I can't use sizeof to get the array length.  It also doesn't seem to work for arrays of char *'s.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Actually ... the sizeof trick works just fine until I pass the array into a function.  Then it seems to not work any more.  Is there a way around that?

Comment: @qwerty9967 When you pass an array into a function by pointer, you should always pass the size of the array as well, unless the function infers the size of the array from the array contents (e.g. if the last element contains terminating value etc.). That's why C++ has std::vector, so passing it by reference will solve your problem.

Comment: @T.E.D: Sometimes you need to modify the resulting vector. For example, you may need to always have some default parameters and sometimes add a few customized to them.

Comment: Doesn't this imply that two duplicate copies of the integers are now being stored in memory? Is there at least a way to destroy the `static const int arr[]` afterward to free up that memory? Even without the `static` keyword, a global variable would remain allocated for the entirety of the program. This could become an issue when dealing with many/large vectors of doubles, strings, etc.

Comment: A solution involving an auxiliary variable, `sizeof()` and multiple arithmetic operations including a division is anything but "the easiest way". -1.

Comment: This answer could be slightly improved by accounting for the introduction of `constexpr` to the language.

Answer (score 766):

If your compiler supports C++11, you can simply do:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

This is available in GCC [as of version 4.4](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html). Unfortunately, VC++ 2010 seems to be lagging behind in this respect.

Alternatively, the [Boost.Assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html) library uses non-macro magic to allow the following:

```
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
...
std::vector<int> v = boost::assign::list_of(1)(2)(3)(4);
```

Or:

```
#include <boost/assign/std/vector.hpp>
using namespace boost::assign;
...
std::vector<int> v;
v += 1, 2, 3, 4;
```

But keep in mind that this has some overhead (basically, `list_of` constructs a `std::deque` under the hood) so for performance-critical code you'd be better off doing as Yacoby says.

Comment: Since vectors are self-sizing, would it be ok to initialize it as empty too? Like in the constructor: `this->vect = {};` ?

Comment: @Azurespot You can just initialise it, and it will be empty: `std::vector<T> vector;`

Comment: Just in case somebody may be curious about `std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};`, vector's `initializer list constructor` will be called for this sort of initializing, its doc can be find in the [`C++ 11` section](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/).

Answer (score 142):

If you can, use the modern C++[11,14,17,20,...] way:

```
std::vector<int> ints = {10, 20, 30};
```

The old way of looping over a variable-length array or using `sizeof()` is truly terrible on the eyes and completely unnecessary in terms of mental overhead. Yuck.

Comment: In fairness, this was originally a C++03 question, but I hope that people/companies adopt the new standards. C++ still needs a variable-length array (VLA) implementation in the standard library similar to what is available in Eigen and Boost.

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach is problematic in some cases e.g. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1467. Yuck.

Comment: If "list-initialization of an aggregate from an object of the same type" is your thing, probably there are bigger problems in your codebase... I can think of no application where it would justify the debugging problems.

Comment: answer from 2018 and still uses `={}`?

Comment: Still no need of `=`

Comment: The answer uses the `=` and `{}` symbols to simplify the translation for programmers coming from other languages. Omitting the assignment operator when you are in fact assigning values is just weird. The compiler will remove the `=` operator anyway.

Answer (score 82):

In C++0x you will be able to do it in the same way that you did with an array, but not in the current standard.

With only language support you can use:

```
int tmp[] = { 10, 20, 30 };
std::vector<int> v( tmp, tmp+3 ); // use some utility to avoid hardcoding the size here
```

If you can add other libraries you could try boost::assignment:

```
vector<int> v = list_of(10)(20)(30);
```

To avoid hardcoding the size of an array:

```
// option 1, typesafe, not a compile time constant
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
inline std::size_t size_of_array( T (&)[N] ) {
   return N;
}
// option 2, not typesafe, compile time constant
#define ARRAY_SIZE(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))

// option 3, typesafe, compile time constant
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
char (&sizeof_array( T(&)[N] ))[N];    // declared, undefined
#define ARRAY_SIZE(x) sizeof(sizeof_array(x))
```

Comment: Of course I didn't downvote but I have a question anyway: when is the size of an array not a compile time constant? I.e., in which cases would you use the first solution in your second snippet as opposed to the third one?

Comment: +vote from my side. In C++0x you could make a `constexpr` of option 1. But then again, this won't be used anymore then :S

Comment: @Manuel, the size of the array is part of the type, and as such it is a compile time constant. Now, option 1 uses that compile time constant 'N' as return value for a function. The return of a function is not a compile time, but runtime value, even if it will probably get inlined as the constant value at the place of call. The difference is that you cannot do: `int another[size_of_array(array)]`, while you can do `int another[ARRAY_SIZE(array)]`.

Comment: @Manuel: incomplete array types also exist, like `int[]`. I can put a declaration of such an array in a header and define it somewhere else (with completed type). Then, the size is not known during compilation of all other traslation units that just include the header. Array-to-pointer decay still works, sizeof does not.

Comment: In option 3: I don't really get what you mean with "declared, undefined
"?
So the variable will not take additional memory?

Comment: @To1ne that is actually a function declaration, not a variable. The reason for or defining it is that we don't actually want the function for anything else other than the `sizeof` expression that does not need a definition. While you can actually provide a definition, to do it right would require the static allocation of an array and returning a reference to it, and the next question would be what would make sense as values for the array? (Also note that this means one array per type/size combination of the function's instantiations!) Since the is no sensible use for it, I'd rather avoid it.

Comment: The option 1 doesn't work in the case of empty array:
`int arr[0] = {};`
`std::size_t num = size_of_array(arr);`
Compiler will print something like:
`no matching function for call to 'size_of_array(int [0])'
std::size_t num = size_of_array(arr);`

Comment: @mhd: You cannot construct an empty array in the language. 'int arr[0] = {};' is not valid C++ code. But you are right that if you want to initialize an empty vector and a non-empty vector you  will have to use different constructs. Since C++11 this is a non-issue as you can use the initializer list constructor

Comment: Your ARRAY_SIZE macro `#define ARRAY_SIZE(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))` is more unsafe than necessary.  Please parenthesize it properly: `#define ARRAY_SIZE(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))`  or `#define ARRAY_SIZE(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(*(x)))`

Answer (score 80):

In C++11:

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
...
vector<int> vec1 { 10, 20, 30 };
// or
vector<int> vec2 = { 10, 20, 30 };
```

Using Boost `list_of`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
using std::vector;
...
vector<int> vec = boost::assign::list_of(10)(20)(30);
```

Using Boost assign:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/assign/std/vector.hpp>
using std::vector;
...
vector<int> vec;
vec += 10, 20, 30;
```

Conventional STL:

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
...
static const int arr[] = {10,20,30};
vector<int> vec (arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) );
```

Conventional STL with generic macros:

```
#include <vector>
#define ARRAY_SIZE(ar) (sizeof(ar) / sizeof(ar[0])
#define ARRAY_END(ar) (ar + ARRAY_SIZE(ar))
using std::vector;
...
static const int arr[] = {10,20,30};
vector<int> vec (arr, ARRAY_END(arr));
```

Conventional STL with a vector initializer macro:

```
#include <vector>
#define INIT_FROM_ARRAY(ar) (ar, ar + sizeof(ar) / sizeof(ar[0])
using std::vector;
...
static const int arr[] = {10,20,30};
vector<int> vec INIT_FROM_ARRAY(arr);
```

Comment: C++11 also support `std::begin` and `std::end` for array, so a vector can also be initialized like `static const int arr[] = {10,20,30}; vector<int> vec(begin(arr), end(arr));`.

Answer (score 59):

I tend to declare

```
template< typename T, size_t N >
std::vector<T> makeVector( const T (&data)[N] )
{
    return std::vector<T>(data, data+N);
}
```

in a utility header somewhere and then all that's required is:

```
const double values[] = { 2.0, 1.0, 42.0, -7 };
std::vector<double> array = makeVector(values);
```

Comment: This technique can also be used to overload a function to accept an array with typed size.

Comment: Can you explain the `const T (&data)[N]` part? How is the size of the array deduced in your call `makeVector(values)`?

Answer (score 47):

#### Before C++11

```
static const int arr[] = {10, 20, 30};
vector<int> v(arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]));
```

We can also do:

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(SomeValue);
// ...
```

#### Since C++11

Using [copy-list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

```
vector<int> v = {1, 3, 5, 7};
```

We can do this using [direct-list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) well:

```
vector<int> v {1, 3, 5, 7}; // Notice .. no "=" sign
```

#### Since C++17

[Class template argument deduction (CTAD)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) lets you omit the template arguments:

```
vector v = {1, 3, 5, 7};
```

Comment: Doesn't work for a vector with a single element.

Comment: @ar2015 yes, it does. Overload resolution prefers the constructor which takes `std::initializer_list` over the constructor taking `std::size_t`. As long as you use braces, it works.

Answer (score 29):

Starting with:

```
int a[] = {10, 20, 30}; //I'm assuming 'a' is just a placeholder
```

If you don't have a C++11 compiler and you don't want to use Boost:

```
const int a[] = {10, 20, 30};
const std::vector<int> ints(a, a+sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)); //Make it const if you can
```

If you don't have a C++11 compiler and can use Boost:

```
#include <boost/assign.hpp>
const std::vector<int> ints = boost::assign::list_of(10)(20)(30);
```

If you do have a C++11 compiler:

```
const std::vector<int> ints = {10,20,30};
```

Answer (score 23):

For vector initialisation -

```
vector<int> v = {10, 20, 30}
```

can be done if you have a [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) compiler.

Else, you can have an array of the data and then use a *for* loop.

```
int array[] = {10,20,30}
for(unsigned int i=0; i<sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]); i++)
{
     v.push_back(array[i]);
}
```

Apart from these, there are various other ways described in previous answers using some code. In my opinion, these ways are easy to remember and quick to write.

Answer (score 22):

The easiest way to do it is:

```
vector<int> ints = {10, 20, 30};
```

Comment: Which compiler? Are you using C++11 here?

Comment: g++ 4.6.3 with -std=c++0x.

Answer (score 16):

If your compiler supports [Variadic macros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro) (which is true for most modern compilers), then you can use the following macro to turn vector initialization into a one-liner:

```
#define INIT_VECTOR(type, name, ...) \
static const type name##_a[] = __VA_ARGS__; \
vector<type> name(name##_a, name##_a + sizeof(name##_a) / sizeof(*name##_a))
```

With this macro, you can define an initialized vector with code like this:

```
INIT_VECTOR(int, my_vector, {1, 2, 3, 4});
```

This would create a new vector of ints named my_vector with the elements 1, 2, 3, 4.

Answer (score 16):

I build my own solution using `va_arg`. This solution is C++98 compliant.

```
#include <cstdarg>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> initVector (int len, ...)
{
  std::vector<T> v;
  va_list vl;
  va_start(vl, len);
  for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    v.push_back(va_arg(vl, T));
  va_end(vl);
  return v;
}

int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> v = initVector<int> (7,702,422,631,834,892,104,772);
  for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = v.begin() ; it != v.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/1lIACz)

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to use Boost, but want to enjoy syntax like

```
std::vector<int> v;
v+=1,2,3,4,5;
```

just include this chunk of code

```
template <class T> class vector_inserter{
public:
    std::vector<T>& v;
    vector_inserter(std::vector<T>& v):v(v){}
    vector_inserter& operator,(const T& val){v.push_back(val);return *this;}
};
template <class T> vector_inserter<T> operator+=(std::vector<T>& v,const T& x){
    return vector_inserter<T>(v),x;
}
```

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out how to use this code, but it looks interesting.

Comment: It's like one of the comment above said. Just overloading += and comma operator.


Putting parenthesis for clarity :
`((((v+=1),2),3),4),5)`

This is how it works: First,
`vector<T> += T` returns a vector_inserter lets call it `vi` which encapsulate the original vector then `vi,T` add T to original vector which `vi` encapsulate and return it self so that we can do `vi,T` again.

Comment: this code didn't worked correctly on gcc 4.2.1 i think because of returning reference to a local variable inside += operator but idea is exellent. i edited code and there appears one more copy constructor. flow is now -> += -> ctor -> comma -> copy -> dtor -> comma ...... -> comma -> dtor.

Comment: I'd have probably overloaded << instead of +=.  At least << already has vague side effect rules because of bit shifts and cout

Answer (score 11):

In C++11:

```
static const int a[] = {10, 20, 30};
vector<int> vec (begin(a), end(a));
```

Comment: If you're using C++11 already, you may as well go for the direct approach - `vector<int> arr = {10, 20, 30};`.

Comment: Actually I had an incoming int[] (some C lib) and wanted to push into a vector (C++ lib). This answer helped, the rest didn't ;-)

Answer (score 10):

A more recent duplicate question has [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8907356) by [Viktor Sehr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100724/viktor-sehr). For me, it is compact, visually appealing (looks like you are 'shoving' the values in), doesn't require [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) or a third-party module, and avoids using an extra (written) variable. Below is how I am using it with a few changes. I may switch to extending the function of vector and/or `va_arg` in the future instead.

---

```
// Based on answer by "Viktor Sehr" on Stack Overflow
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/8907356
//
template <typename T>
class mkvec {
    public:
        typedef mkvec<T> my_type;
        my_type& operator<< (const T& val) {
            data_.push_back(val);
            return *this;
        }
        my_type& operator<< (const std::vector<T>& inVector) {
            this->data_.reserve(this->data_.size() + inVector.size());
            this->data_.insert(this->data_.end(), inVector.begin(), inVector.end());
            return *this;
        }
        operator std::vector<T>() const {
            return data_;
        }
    private:
        std::vector<T> data_;
};

std::vector<int32_t> vec1;
std::vector<int32_t> vec2;

vec1 = mkvec<int32_t>() << 5 << 8 << 19 << 79;
// vec1 = (5, 8, 19, 79)
vec2 = mkvec<int32_t>() << 1 << 2 << 3 << vec1 << 10 << 11 << 12;
// vec2 = (1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 19, 79, 10, 11, 12)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do that using *boost::assign*:

```
vector<int> values;
values += 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;
```

[Details are here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html).

Comment: I haven't seen a worse case of operator overloading abuse in a long time.  Does the `+=` there tack on 1,2,3,4.. to the end of values, or does it _add_ 1 to the 1st element, 2 to the 2nd element, 3 to the 3rd element (as syntax like this should in MATLAB-like languages)

Answer (score 7):

The below methods can be used to initialize the vector in C++.

1. `int arr[] = {1, 3, 5, 6}; vector<int> v(arr, arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));`
2. `vector<int>v; v.push_back(1); v.push_back(2); v.push_back(3);` and so on
3. `vector<int>v = {1, 3, 5, 7};`

The third one is allowed only in [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) onwards.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of good answers here, but since I independently arrived at my own before reading this, I figured I'd toss mine up here anyway...

Here's a method that I'm using for this which will work universally across compilers and platforms:

Create a struct or class as a container for your collection of objects. Define an operator overload function for `<<`.

```
class MyObject;

struct MyObjectList
{
    std::list<MyObject> objects;
    MyObjectList& operator<<( const MyObject o )
    { 
        objects.push_back( o );
        return *this; 
    }
};
```

You can create functions which take your struct as a parameter, e.g.:

```
someFunc( MyObjectList &objects );
```

Then, you can call that function, like this:

```
someFunc( MyObjectList() << MyObject(1) <<  MyObject(2) <<  MyObject(3) );
```

That way, you can build and pass a dynamically sized collection of objects to a function in one single clean line!

Answer (score 4):

If you want something on the same general order as Boost::assign without creating a dependency on Boost, the following is at least vaguely similar:

```
template<class T>
class make_vector {
    std::vector<T> data;
public:
    make_vector(T const &val) { 
        data.push_back(val);
    }

    make_vector<T> &operator,(T const &t) {
        data.push_back(t);
        return *this;
    }

    operator std::vector<T>() { return data; }
};

template<class T> 
make_vector<T> makeVect(T const &t) { 
    return make_vector<T>(t);
}
```

While I wish the syntax for using it was cleaner, it's still not particularly awful:

```
std::vector<int> x = (makeVect(1), 2, 3, 4);
```

Answer (score 4):

***"How do I create an STL vector and initialize it like the above? What is the best way to do so with the minimum typing effort?"***

The easiest way to initialize a vector as you've initialized your built-in array is using an initializer list *which was introduced in C++11*.

```
// Initializing a vector that holds 2 elements of type int.
Initializing:
std::vector<int> ivec = {10, 20};


// The push_back function is more of a form of assignment with the exception of course
//that it doesn't obliterate the value of the object it's being called on.
Assigning
ivec.push_back(30);
```

`ivec` is 3 elements in size after Assigning (labeled statement) is executed.

Comment: In the similar lines , I am trying to initialise the map, std::map<int, bool> catinfo = { {1, false} }; But then get this error error: in C++98 'catinfo' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'

Answer (score 4):

```
typedef std::vector<int> arr;

arr a {10, 20, 30};       // This would be how you initialize while defining
```

To compile use:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++  <filename.cpp>
```

Comment: Question states C++ 03 (not 11)

Comment: I think it didn't specify 03 when I answered this. Don't remember perfectly though. However, it is still a useful answer for someone looking for a quick solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
// Before C++11
// I used following methods:

// 1.
int A[] = {10, 20, 30};                              // original array A

unsigned sizeOfA = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);           // calculate the number of elements

                                                     // declare vector vArrayA,
std::vector<int> vArrayA(sizeOfA);                   // make room for all
                                                     // array A integers
                                                     // and initialize them to 0 

for(unsigned i=0; i<sizeOfA; i++)
    vArrayA[i] = A[i];                               // initialize vector vArrayA


//2.
int B[] = {40, 50, 60, 70};                          // original array B

std::vector<int> vArrayB;                            // declare vector vArrayB
for (unsigned i=0; i<sizeof(B)/sizeof(B[0]); i++)
    vArrayB.push_back(B[i]);                         // initialize vArrayB

//3.
int C[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};                              // original array C

std::vector<int> vArrayC;                            // create an empty vector vArrayC
vArrayC.resize(sizeof(C)/sizeof(C[0]));              // enlarging the number of 
                                                     // contained elements
for (unsigned i=0; i<sizeof(C)/sizeof(C[0]); i++)
     vArrayC.at(i) = C[i];                           // initialize vArrayC


// A Note:
// Above methods will work well for complex arrays
// with structures as its elements.
```

Answer (score 4):

If the array is:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
int len = (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])); // finding length of array
vector < int > v;
v.assign(arr, arr+len); // assigning elements from array to vector
```

Comment: Does this code compile? That last line looks like it would be a syntax error, since it would be parsed as `(std::v).assign(arr, arr + len);`, and there's no `v` in `namespace std`. Or did you mean `std::vector<int> v; v.assign(...);`?

Comment: Note that for you can use: `len = std::size(arr);`. It does the same thing under the hood.

Answer (score 4):

It is pretty convenient to create a vector inline without defining variable when writing test, for example:

```cpp
assert(MyFunction() == std::vector<int>{1, 3, 4}); // <- this.
```

Answer (score 4):

There are various ways to hardcode a vector. I will share few ways:

1. Initializing by pushing values one by one

   ```
   // Create an empty vector
   vector<int> vect;

   vect.push_back(10);
   vect.push_back(20);
   vect.push_back(30);
   ```
2. Initializing like arrays

   ```
   vector<int> vect{ 10, 20, 30 };
   ```
3. Initializing from an array

   ```
   int arr[] = { 10, 20, 30 };
   int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

   vector<int> vect(arr, arr + n);
   ```
4. Initializing from another vector

   ```
   vector<int> vect1{ 10, 20, 30 };

   vector<int> vect2(vect1.begin(), vect1.end());
   ```

Comment: That last one could be simplified to `auto vect2 = vect1;` or `vector<int> vect2 = vect1`, right?

Answer (score 3):

Related, you can use the following if you want to have a vector completely ready to go in a quick statement (e.g. immediately passing to another function):

```
#define VECTOR(first,...) \
   ([](){ \
   static const decltype(first) arr[] = { first,__VA_ARGS__ }; \
   std::vector<decltype(first)> ret(arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr)); \
   return ret;})()
```

example function

```
template<typename T>
void test(std::vector<T>& values)
{
    for(T value : values)
        std::cout<<value<<std::endl;
}
```

example use

```
test(VECTOR(1.2f,2,3,4,5,6));
```

though be careful about the decltype, make sure the first value is clearly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

B. Stroustrup describes a nice way to chain operations in **16.2.10 Selfreference** on page 464 in the C++11 edition of the Prog. Lang. where a function returns a reference, here modified to a vector. This way you can chain like `v.pb(1).pb(2).pb(3);` but may be too much work for such small gains.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class chain
{
private:
    std::vector<T> _v;
public:
    chain& pb(T a) {
        _v.push_back(a);
        return *this;
    };
    std::vector<T> get() { return _v; };
};

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    chain<int> v{};

    v.pb(1).pb(2).pb(3);

    for (auto& i : v.get()) {
        cout << i << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> 1
>   2
>   3

Comment: The armadillo library does this for matrix initialisation but uses the << operator instead of a named function: http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#element_initialisation

Answer (score 1):

The simplest, ergonomic way (with C++ 11 or later):

```
auto my_ints = {1,2,3};
```

Comment: Won't this deduce `my_ints` as a `std::initializer_list<int>` rather than a `std::vector<int>`?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to have it in your own class:

```
#include <initializer_list>
Vector<Type>::Vector(std::initializer_list<Type> init_list) : _size(init_list.size()),
_capacity(_size),
_data(new Type[_size])
{
    int idx = 0;
    for (auto it = init_list.begin(); it != init_list.end(); ++it)
        _data[idx++] = *it;
}
```