# How can I concisely initialize a safe collection in C++?

Tags: c++, list, collections, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++: Easiest way to initialize an STL vector with hardcoded elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236197/c-easiest-way-to-initialize-an-stl-vector-with-hardcoded-elements)

I'm learning C++ right now, and I'm looking for a way to quickly and easily initialize a "safe" collection (like a vector) with different values for each element. I'm accustomed to Python's concise list/tuple initializations, and I want to know if there's an equivalent syntax trick or collection type in C++.

For example, if I want to initialize a list of unique Payment objects in Python, I can do this:

```
payments = [Payment(10, 2), Payment(20, 4), Payment(30, 6)]
```

However, in order to initialize a vector of Payment structures in C++, I need to write something like this:

```
Payment tempPayments[] = {
    {10, 2},
    {20, 4},
    {30, 6}
};
vector<Payment> examplePayments(tempPayments, tempPayments + 
    sizeof(tempPayments) / sizeof(Payment));
```

Is there an easier way to initialize a vector with unique structures, or another safe collection that's more convenient?

Comment: Lots of dupes including http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236197/c-easiest-way-to-initialize-an-stl-vector-with-hardcoded-elements

Comment: Neil's right; apparently, I'm already using the easiest method (without Boost).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into [Boost.Assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html), particularly [list_of](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#list_of). It allows you to initialize a collection using code such as:

```
const vector<int> primes = list_of(2)(3)(5)(7)(11);
```