# Using STL/Boost to initialize a hard-coded set<vector<int> >

Tags: c++, stl, boost, initialization

Like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236197/c-easiest-way-to-initialize-an-stl-vector-with-hardcoded-elements) already asked, I'd like to initialize a container using STL where the elements are hard-coded in the cleanest manner possible. In this case, the elements are a doubly nested container:

```
set<vector<int> > A;
```

And I'd like (for example) to put the following values in:

```
A = [[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,0]];
```

C++0x fine, using `g++` 4.4.1. STL is preferable as I don't use Boost for any other parts of the code (though I wouldn't mind an example with it!).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This does use g++ 4.4.1, with -std=c++0x

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    set<vector<int>> A = {{0,0,1},{0,1,0},{1,0,0},{0,0,0}};

}
```

Comment: Wow, thats amazing and quite simple! That should be _the_ answer to the question I linked to as well. Any good reason why it took so long for the standard to implement this functionality?

Comment: @Hooked: Standards aren't exactly quick. :) (10 years in between ISO standards.) Previous standards had other things to worry about.

Comment: +1 : Wow, works with g++ (GCC) 4.6.0 20100421 (experimental) with -std=c++0x.

Comment: Nice. Shouldn't c++0x allow us to write `set<vector<int>>` instead of `set<vector<int> >` ?

Answer (score 7):

```
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp> 
#include <vector>
#include <set>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::assign;

int main()
{
    set<vector<int> > A;

    A = list_of
        (list_of(0)(0)(1))
        (list_of(0)(1)(0))
        (list_of(1)(0)(0));
        (list_of(0)(0)(0));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, nested use of list_of's, nice thank you! Any chance that this could be done only with a one-line += operator?

Comment: `list_of()` is useful for quick code but is too slow and resource intensive for production.  I use it extensively in unit tests but wouldn't touch it otherwise.