# How to initialize a string set in C++?

Tags: c++, string, set

I have a few words to be initialized while declaring a string set.

```
...
using namespace std;
set<string> str;

/*str has to contain some names like "John", "Kelly", "Amanda", "Kim".*/
```

I don't want to use `str.insert("Name");` each time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can take advantage of initializer lists if you're using C++11. See #5 in this [constructor list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set) and the relevant part of Stroustrup's [C++11 FAQ](http://stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#init-list).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Using C++11:

```
std::set<std::string> str = {"John", "Kelly", "Amanda", "Kim"};
```

Otherwise:

```
std::string tmp[] = {"John", "Kelly", "Amanda", "Kim"};
std::set<std::string> str(tmp, tmp + sizeof(tmp) / sizeof(tmp[0]));
```

Answer (score 22):

**In C++11**

Use [initializer lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Initializer_lists).

```
std::set<std::string> str { "John", "Kelly", "Amanda", "Kim" };
```

**In C++03** *(I'm voting up @john's answer.  It's very close what I would have given.)*

Use the `std::set( InputIterator first, InputIterator last, ...)` constructor.

```
std::string init[] = { "John", "Kelly", "Amanda", "Kim" };
std::set<std::string> str(init, init + sizeof(init)/sizeof(init[0]) );
```

Answer (score 7):

There's lots of ways you can do this, here's one

```
string init[] = { "John", "Kelly", "Amanda", "Kim" };
set<string> str(init, init + 4);
```

Comment: how to chose the second element of the set here? like an array[1]

Comment: That `+4` is pretty dangerous, I wouldn't promote bad practice

Answer (score 6):

if you are not c++0x:

You should look at boost::assign

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#list_of

Also take a look at:

[Using STL/Boost to initialize a hard-coded set<vector<int> >](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742549/using-stl-boost-to-initialize-a-hard-coded-setvectorint)

```
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp> 
#include <vector>
#include <set>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::assign;

int main()
{
    set<int>  A = list_of(1)(2)(3)(4);

    return 0; // not checked if compile
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's multiple ways to do this. Using C++11, you can try either...

```
std::set<std::string> set {
  "John", "Kelly", "Amanda", "Kim"
};
```

... which uses an initializer list, or [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end)...

```
std::string vals[] = { "John", "Kelly", "Amanda", "Kim" };
std::set<std::string> set(std::begin(vals), std::end(vals));
```

Comment: It's not recommendable call a variable with a name in the `std` namespace (`set` in this case). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/2436175

Comment: @Antonio the passages referencing `std` there (lib.global.names, lib.reserved.name) govern standard library implementation compliance, not the naming of local variables in user code; whether you or another user find it 'recommendable' to use any of the thousands of names that also appear in `std` namespace is one thing, but I fear it has little to do with correctness

Answer (score 2):

Create an array of strings(C array) and initialize the set with it's values (array pointers as iterators):
`std::string values[] = { "John", "Kelly", "Amanda", "Kim" };

std::set s(values,values + sizeof(values)/sizeof(std::string));`