# Creating a c_vector

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, boost-ublas

Is it possible to create a `c_vector<int, 3>` with the values `[12 398 -34]` (as an example), in a single line?

As far as [I can see](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp) the only viable constructor is:

```
c_vector(vector_expression<AE> const&)
```

which takes a `VectorExpression`, which seem to be all the other kind of vectors, like `zero_vector` and `scalar_vector` that are dynamically allocated.

Is there something like a `std::initializer_list<T>` constructor that I can use? Or what `VectorExpression` should I use for this simple task?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2742549

Comment: @RobertHarvery Erm. Sorry, no. This is not a duplicate of that question. `std::vector` and `boost::numeric::ublas::c_vector` are entirely different beasts. Yes, the answers there make use of Boost.Assign which might or may not be relevant here, but the question is really regarding what `VectorExpression` can be used here. Good to see you though.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It has literally the exact same problems as the one you closed the question with. And I've highlighted them in my previous comment.

Comment: How come you're not using std::vector?  Seems like it has a leg up here.

Comment: Have you had a look here?  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html

Comment: @RobertHarvey 1) `std::vector` is dynamically allocated.  2) `boost::numeric::ublas::c_vector` is a vector in the mathematical sense. Specifically it allows vector addition, cross product, and all that fun mathy stuff.

Comment: Give it another 30 seconds or so, and this is going to be less trouble to just write as a two-liner.  And probably more standard.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, I've browser through Boost.Assign, and I haven't noticed anything related to `c_vector` or similar. The problem here is that the constructor accepts a `VectorExpression`, which seems to be something very specific to Boost.uBLAS.

Comment: Have you tried implementing a vector expression that can be constructed (maybe from a helper function) from an initializer list?  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/expression_concept.htm#2VectorExpression Boring boilerplate, but should work, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled upon this in the `assignment.hpp` header:

```
v <<= 1,2,3;
```

I suppose there might be more useful methods in there, if you look closely. E.g.

```
vector<double> a(6, 0);
a <<= 1, 2, move_to(5), 3;
```

will result in: `1 2 0 0 0 3` and

```
matrix<double> A(3, 3, 0);
A <<= 1, 2, next_row(),
3, 4, begin1(), 1;
```

will result in:

```
1 2 1
3 4 0
0 0 0
```

---

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e5b59200a311b8a)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector_expression.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/traits/c_array.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/assignment.hpp>

namespace ublas = boost::numeric::ublas;

int main() {
    using V = ublas::c_vector<int, 3>;

    V v;
    v <<= 1,2,3;

    for (auto i : v)
        std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

Prints

```
1 2 3
```

Comment: I see. My problem was with construction more than anything though (being able to construct a vector with those values).