# How to store fixed length strings inside a std::vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I want to mimic a structure:

```
char [][40] = { "Stack", "Overflow", "Exchange", "Network" };
```

using a `std::vector`, so I can populate it at runtime and dynamically change the size of the `vector`, but keeping the member elements located inside fixed size blocks.

Static initialization is not my question - I can do that using `boost::assign` or other tricks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: Easiest way to initialize an STL vector with hardcoded elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236197/c-easiest-way-to-initialize-an-stl-vector-with-hardcoded-elements)

Comment: @Kerrek SB No I do not have C++11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use something like [Boost.Array](http://www.boost.org/libs/array/index.html):

```
typedef boost::array<char, 40> arr_t;
std::vector<arr_t> vec;
{
    arr_t arr = { "Stack" };
    vec.push_back(arr);
}
{
    arr_t arr = { "Overflow" };
    vec.push_back(arr);
}
{
    arr_t arr = { "Exchange" };
    vec.push_back(arr);
}
{
    arr_t arr = { "Network" };
    vec.push_back(arr);
}
```

If you're using a reasonably recent compiler, instead of Boost you can probably use `std::array<>` (C++11; `#include <array>`) or `std::tr1::array<>` (C++03 with TR1; `#include <array>` or `#include <tr1/array>`, depending on platform).

Comment: This looks interesting. Do you know if vec would be contiguous. i.e can I pass &vec[0] to a C function?

Comment: @karim : Yes, each contained `array<>` is stored contiguously in memory. E.g., a `vector<>` with 2 elements will have a contiguous 80 byte buffer.

Comment: @karim What kind of weird C function takes n*40 bytes of char data with null separators in between?

Comment: @pmr : I don't know about the OP's requirements, but offhand I know of a few Windows API functions that work with null-delimited, double-null-terminated lists of strings.

Comment: @pmr  Think of a database api function that accepts data as an array i.e. many rows to be loaded in one roundtrip.

Comment: @ildjarn That makes more sense. But in this case there is the waste of memory and the need to pass the size of the array etc. Maybe OP misunderstands the requirements of the function he is going to call?

Comment: @karim You need a new database.

Comment: @ildjarn is this supposed to work? char* cv = (char*)&vec[0];
cout << cv << endl; It prints the first element only

Comment: @karim : `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, char const*)` stops printing as soon as a null character is encountered. If you want to print past the first element, then the first element cannot contain any null characters. This is C++ 101 ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn  And this too? printf("%s\n",&vec[0])? I am still trying to convince myself that &vec[0] as constructed above ( nested ) truly gives me contiguous memory

Comment: @karim : All C-string functions operate on a null-termination basis -- how else would it know when the C-string ends? If you want to verify that the elements are stored in contiguous memory (which they are, and have to be, according to basic C++ rules regarding `operator new[]`), then open a debugger and look at the memory directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct fixed_string { 
    char data[40];

    fixed_string(char const *init);
};

std::vector<fixed_string> whatever;
```

If you have C++11 (or at least TR1), you probably want to use `std::array` instead of `fixed_string`. I think Boost has an equivalent as well.

In case anybody's wondering why I put it in a `struct`, instead of creating a vector of array directly: because items in a `vector` need to be copyable and assignable, and a bare array is neither.

Answer (score 0):

May be `vector` in `vector` helps. Here size is fixed, strings could be used in pure C.

```
vector< vector<char> > vector_of_strings;

// Add new string
vector_of_strings.push_back( vector<char>(40) );
// use the string
strcpy( &vector_of_strings[0][0], "text" );
```

Comment: Do you think this will have contiguous memory like the C array in the question?

Comment: If you're willing to go for nested containers, then why not a `std::vector<std::tr1::array<char, 40>>`?

Comment: @All: [Check this out!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849168/are-stdvector-elements-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous)

Comment: @Kerrek SB: tr1 is not supported by all of the compilers.

Comment: @Naszta : This doesn't have contiguous memory -- the nested `vector<char>` objects are stored in contiguous memory, but the actual data buffers are not (nor are they fixed-size as was specifically requested in the question).

Comment: @Naszta I didn't think nested vectors would be contiguous but I may be wrong.

Comment: @Naszta: If you *really* can't dig up a TR1 (how old is your compiler?) you can write an `array<T,N>` yourself pretty quickly and easily, and as a bonus you could be sure that your `std::vector<MyArray<char,40>>` is actually contiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Parapura's answer is correct, but you will be storing the pointers to the strings. If the original character array falls out of scope you will lose the information posted. If this vector is used elsewhere, it should allocate (and deallocate!) it's own memory. This can be done when the input is taken.

Here's a sample program that does that.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

int main()
{
    int numEntries = 4;
    const int strlen = 40;

    // Parapura's correct answer, but let's expand this further
    vector<char*> strvec;
    char* input = 0;
    int i;

    cout << "Enter four names." << endl;
    for (i=0; i<numEntries; i++)
    {
        // Allocate some memory to store in the vector
        input = new char[strlen];
        cout << "Name: ";
        cin.get(input, strlen);
        cin.ignore(strlen, '\n');

        // Push the populated memory into the vector.
        // Now we can let 'input' fall out of scope.
        strvec.push_back(input);
    }
    cout << endl;

    /* -- cool code here! -- */

    cout << "List of names." << endl;
    for (i=0; i<numEntries; i++)
    {
        cout << strvec[i] << endl;
    }

    /* -- more cool code! -- */

    // don't forget to clean up!
    for (i=0; i<numEntries; i++)
    {
        delete[] strvec[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```