# Passing attributes to Rcpp::Function

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm trying to pass a vector to the R function called from within Rcpp:

```
Rcpp::Function aperm("aperm");
int perm[3] = {2,1,3};
arr = aperm(arr, Rcpp::Named("perm", perm));
```

I've tried to wrap the perm before calling aperm but in both cases I am getting various Rcpp errors:

```
arr = aperm(arr, Rcpp::Named("perm", Rcpp::wrap(perm)));
```

Is it possible to pass a vector as a parameter to an R function when calling it from Rcpp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is but you need to make sure you use `Rcpp::wrap()` -- maybe explicitly if the implicit templated form is not called for you.  Here, your C function array `perm` is of the wrong form.  Make that an `IntegerVector` and things should work.

In general, *complete* and *reproducible* examples *posted to the rcpp-devel list* are the best way about this.

Comment: vector<int> permVector (perm, perm + sizeof(perm) / sizeof(perm[0]) ); Did the trick, thanks!

Comment: Yes, `std::vector<int>` also gets the implicit form of `Rcpp::wrap`.

Comment: Also, more generally speaking, there is _no reason_ why you want an `int[]` array in 2012. The STL vector or the Rcpp vector are preferable (IMHO) on every count.

Comment: That's the solution I found as a best way of initializing an STL vector: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2236227/328989

Comment: Right -- you can do a little better with C++11 (see eg [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Initializer_lists)), also adding `-std=c++0x` to the `g++` flags. Mind you, CRAN would not allow that in an uploaded package but for local use it is just fine.

Comment: In that case, you might want : `wrap( perm, perm + 3 )`

Comment: Or perhaps `IntegerVector::create(2,1,3)`