# Cant initialize a std array into a std vector

Tags: c++, c++11

Not an actual problem but rather a fashion crisis..

```
 vector<array<unsigned int, 3>> tri;
 tri.push_back(array<unsigned int, 3> {0, 0, 0});
```

gives me a syntax error. Is there any way to initialize a std array with values into a vector in one line?

Comment: And what exactly is this syntax error?

Comment: error C2059: syntax error : ')' on the line of push

Comment: It's for usual array, but maybe it will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236197/c-easiest-way-to-initialize-an-stl-vector-with-hardcoded-elements

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first rule of `std::array` is: when in doubt, add more braces. That's because you're actually initializing the raw array subobject of the `std::array`.

```
tri.push_back(array<unsigned int, 3> {{0, 0, 0}});
```

Both GCC and Clang accept this statement.

Comment: @KarliRaudsepp I am not sure this answer is right. I think the extra braces can be elided here. In any case, as per the C++11 standard, it isn't crystal clear whether they are required or not (this might have been fixed in current drafts).

Comment: @juanchopanza: Clang refuses to compile when the extra braces are not there.

Comment: GCC also accepts the statement without the extra braces: see [here](http://ideone.com/vHPLg7).

Comment: @juanchopanza: yeah, but without them the code works only under GCC, with them under both GCC and Clang. Thus, safer to add them anyway, and I believe Clang may be onto something, as it's not the first time I see GCC accepting some code that is rejected by Clang. More often than not, such cases are seen as legitimate bugs by the GCC devs.

Comment: @juanchopanza: GCC emits a `warning: missing braces around initializer for ‘std::array<unsigned int, 3ul>::value_type [3] {aka unsigned int [3]}’ [-Wmissing-braces]`. So yeah it accepts it, but it still whines.

Comment: @Fanael: That doesn't mean that GCC is wrong. Brace elision is a part of the C++11 standard.

Comment: @Fanael the wording of the C++11 standard isn't completely clear about this. In fact it is plain confusing. They give an example implementation which uses a single plain array, but then they say it is only an example. There is no requirement that `std::array` be an aggregate containing a single aggregate. But as I said, maybe this has been clarified in favour of your solution. But then there is the issue of brace elision. I *think* it applies here.

Comment: @syam but I am not completely convinced this warning is merited. There has been a lot of debate about this issue...

Comment: @NicolBolas: note that doesn't mean that GCC is right, too. Let's just agree that the wording is a mess; and code that compiles under more than one compiler is better than one that compiles under only one.

Comment: @juanchopanza: so in the end I was right, in C++11 brace elision doesn't apply here (8.5.1/11).

Comment: @Fanael Good work! But are the braces required in the first place? I will re-read the relevant section of the standard.

Answer (score 9):

> vs10 still wont accept it :/

And this is why it's important to always provide *complete* information in your questions.

Visual Studio 2010 does not implement uniform initialization (and that is uniform initialization, not merely aggregate initialization). It's not a C++11-compliant compiler; it just has a few C++11 features.

Comment: @CodeClown:  Actually, I think it might be.

Comment: @CodeClown this is the right answer. The selected answer is wrong. I believe the extra braces can be elided in this case.

Comment: @John Dibling @ juanchopanza He just mentions that VS10 is not C++11 compliant. That should go into a comment. He is of course right that the original question is lacking crucial information like what compiler is used. A proper answer should explain what syntax is correct no matter what the compiler supports.

Comment: @CodeClown: The question is "why doesn't this code work?" The answer is "Because you're using a compiler that doesn't accept it."

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Hmmm thinking about it you might be right. Upvoting your answer.