# Is there a way to initialize a container with one line?

Tags: c++, collections

I am looking for vanilla **C++98** solution (no boost, or qt, etc.)

Is there a way to do something [like this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) :

```
// valid in c++ 11
std::vector<Foo> vFoo {Foo1, Foo2, Foo3, Foo4} ;
```

or something like this

```
// Well it is C# but you got the point.
List<Foo> lFoo = new List<Foo>() { Foo1, Foo2, Foo3, Foo4 };
```

For now, I use this one :

```
std::vector<Foo> vFoo;
vFoo.push_back(Foo1);
vFoo.push_back(Foo2);
vFoo.push_back(Foo3);
vFoo.push_back(Foo4);
```

But I find it ugly. Any idea to improve it ? Is there a special way to achieve it ?

Thank you.

Comment: one-liners are not always better, often they are worse in terms of readability

Comment: @DocBrown Thanks for the link! A lot of nice solutions inside. I will close this one.

Comment: C++89? Why not C++81?

Comment: @KerrekSB Hipster stuffs you know. C++89 is so vintage. Well typo error. I correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I build my own solution using `va_arg`.

```
#include <cstdarg>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> initVector (int len, ...)
{
  std::vector<T> v;
  va_list vl;
  va_start(vl, len);
  v.push_back(va_arg(vl, T));
  for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i)
    v.push_back(va_arg(vl, T));
  va_end(vl);
  return v;
}

int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> v = initVector<int> (7,702,422,631,834,892,104,772);
  for(std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = v.begin() ; it != v.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**If you want more answers, follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236197/c03-easiest-way-to-initialize-an-stl-vector-with-hardcoded-elements) of [Doc Brown](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/9113/doc-brown).**

Comment: Please bear in mind that this works only for POD types (the fundamental data types, plus classes without user-defined constructors, virtual members, references etc.).  C++03 standard reference: 5.2.2/7.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. [I learn something new today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c).

Comment: You're welcome.  C++ is full of dark corners I'm afraid ;)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. That's why language support for such constructions was added in C++11. Your existing `push_back` solution is adequate if you cannot use C++11.

Comment: I used my own answer finally. By the way, I love this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2236227/1248177).

Comment: @aloisdg: I don't know, I would call putting variable functions into C++ an outright disservice, to yourself, to future readers, and to humanity. Just say no. (And yes, initializing from an existing collection has always been easy. But that's doing something different.)

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a vector from an array:

```
Foo[] initFoo = { Foo1, Foo2, Foo3, Foo4 };
std::vector<Foo> vFoo(initFoo, initFoo + 4);
```

Comment: Same idea [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2236227/1248177). I like it too.