# How to immediately insert a vector inside a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a vector which elements are of type `vector<int>`, I want to quickly insert elements like this :

```
triangles.push_back(vector<int>(som1, som2, som3))
```

However it doesn't work, no constructor of `vector<int>` matches the argument list.

Is there a quick way to do it, or do I have to create a temporary `vector<int>` variable, push back som1 som 2 and som3, and finally push back the temporary variable in triangles ?

Comment: Does your compiler support C++11?

Comment: Isn't this STL? Shouldn't this be tagged [STL]?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/2236197/21475

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use C++11 initializer lists, all is not lost. Given that your `vector` is named `triangles`, I'm going to assume each sub-vector will always contain exactly three `int`s. If that's the case, you can use a helper function:

```
std::vector<int> MakeTriangle(int a, int b, int c)
{
   std::vector<int> triangle(3);
   triangle[0] = a;
   triangle[1] = b;
   triangle[2] = c;
   return triangle;
}

void f()
{
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> triangles;
   triangles.push_back(MakeTriangle(1, 2, 3));
}
```

For the more general problem, you could write a set of `MakeVector()` function templates taking various numbers of arguments, up to some reasonable limit (again, if you don't have C++11).

If you have boost in your project, you could also make use of `boost::assign`. But I wouldn't drag the entire boost library in just to solve this problem.

Comment: Assuming it will always have 3 elements, why not use a custom struct or a tuple?  Either avoids an extra heap allocation.