# Member List implementation of different class not working

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, initialization, member

I can't seem to get the implementation of my member list correct. I want to DEFAULT initialize my Set members **`nyX`** and **`nyY`**, however I keep getting an error.

```
class Location
{
public:

    vector<int> nyXv = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    vector<int> nyYv = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    Set nyX(vector<int>);
    Set nyY(vector<int>);

    Location();
    ~Location();

    };


    Location::Location()
        :nyX(nyXv), nyY(nyYv)
    {
    }
```

Comment: nyX, nyY are function declarations, not variables.

Answer (score 0):

[Look at this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236197/how-to-initialize-an-stl-vector-with-hardcoded-elements-in-the-easiest-way)

You can initialize you vectors like this:

```
class Location
{
    public:

    vector<int> nyXv;// = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    vector<int> nyYv;// = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    ///...

    Location();
    ~Location();

};


static const int arrX[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
static const int arrY[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
Location::Location()
   :nyXv(arrX, arrX + sizeof(arrX) / sizeof(arrX[0]) )
   ,nyYv(arrY, arrY + sizeof(arrY) / sizeof(arrY[0]))
{
}
```

P.S. Of course there are many ways to improve this code but it should give you an idea