# Proper initialization of multi-dimensional vector

Tags: c++, boost, vector

Assume in C there is following code:

```
const unsigned char C[12][64] = {
        {
            0xB1, 0x08, 0x5B, 0xDA, 0x1E, 0xCA, 0xDA, 0xE9, 0xEB, 0xCB, 0x2F, 0x81, 0xC0, 0x65, 0x7C, 0x1F,
            0x2F, 0x6A, 0x76, 0x43, 0x2E, 0x45, 0xD0, 0x16, 0x71, 0x4E, 0xB8, 0x8D, 0x75, 0x85, 0xC4, 0xFC,
            0x4B, 0x7C, 0xE0, 0x91, 0x92, 0x67, 0x69, 0x01, 0xA2, 0x42, 0x2A, 0x08, 0xA4, 0x60, 0xD3, 0x15,
            0x05, 0x76, 0x74, 0x36, 0xCC, 0x74, 0x4D, 0x23, 0xDD, 0x80, 0x65, 0x59, 0xF2, 0xA6, 0x45, 0x07
        },
        {
            0x6F, 0xA3, 0xB5, 0x8A, 0xA9, 0x9D, 0x2F, 0x1A, 0x4F, 0xE3, 0x9D, 0x46, 0x0F, 0x70, 0xB5, 0xD7,
            0xF3, 0xFE, 0xEA, 0x72, 0x0A, 0x23, 0x2B, 0x98, 0x61, 0xD5, 0x5E, 0x0F, 0x16, 0xB5, 0x01, 0x31,
            0x9A, 0xB5, 0x17, 0x6B, 0x12, 0xD6, 0x99, 0x58, 0x5C, 0xB5, 0x61, 0xC2, 0xDB, 0x0A, 0xA7, 0xCA,
            0x55, 0xDD, 0xA2, 0x1B, 0xD7, 0xCB, 0xCD, 0x56, 0xE6, 0x79, 0x04, 0x70, 0x21, 0xB1, 0x9B, 0xB7
        },

and so on
```

How do I convert it into `std::vector` so that the vector has been initialized all the necessary values?

Under vector I assume something like `vector< vector<uint8_t> >`

Or maybe I'd better use `boost::multi_array`?

Comment: Using `vector` for arrays that don't need dynamic resizing is overkill. Look into `std::array`. Or even keep your `char[][]`.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236197/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-initialize-a-stdvector-with-hardcoded-elements

Answer (score 2):

Starting in C++11 you can initialize a vector with an initializer list.  You can simply change

```
const unsigned char C[12][64] = ...
```

To

```
std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>> C = ...
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6542efecfa67b39d)</kbd>

Comment: And I think he could use the same idea for any STL container, no?  Well except maps, but for other reasons than this.

Comment: @GuyGreer It should work for and standard container that supports an initializer list constructor.  `std::map` can also be created with this.  see:  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c93f8b914031a25

Comment: All I meant about the maps not working is that you need to pass it pairs, which was the "other reasons than this" that I was referring to.  A minor point in the end.

Comment: @GuyGreer Ah.  misunderstood.