# Compiler error: "Non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list."

Tags: c++, qt

When trying to create a simple vector in C++, I get the following error :

> Non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list.

The code I'm using is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector <int> theVector = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    cout << theVector[0];
}
```

I tried to put:

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

into my `.pro` file, saved and rebuilt it. However, I still get the same error. I'm using what I assume to be Qt 5.5, here's what happens when I press `About` if it means anything to you: [Qt's About](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1R9Bf.png).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's your target compiler? VS2013?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way to initialize a std::vector with hardcoded elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236197/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-initialize-a-stdvector-with-hardcoded-elements)

Comment: @Barmar not a duplicate  of that; OP code is correct but the problem is how to configure the compiler for C++11 mode

Comment: @M.M But the answers there show other ways to initialize a vector that will work with older C++ versions.

Comment: @R Sahu I'm not sure, I'm a bit of a beginner. I just use QT Creator and press run?

Answer (score 4):

The following line:

```
vector <int> theVector = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

won't compile pre C++11.

However, you could do something like this:

```
static const int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
vector<int> theVector (arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) );
```