# How to create a vector of class objects

Tags: c++, class, sorting, vector, c++03

I'm trying to create a vector that contains various class times. Afterwards, I would compare these times to see which one is earlier through a sorting function.

**Edit:** after some people mentioned, I do wish to do this with an older version of C++ (prior to 11) because it's what my instructor requested

Would there be a way to do this with push_back?

So far, I have this in my main file:

```
std::vector<Time> times (Time t1(4,5,4), Time t2(3,5,4));
std::sort(times.begin(), times.end(), IsEarlierThan);
```

and this in my Time.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Time.h"

Time::Time() {
    hour = 0;
    minute = 0;
    second = 0;
}

Time::Time(int theHour, int theMinute, int theSecond) {
    hour = theHour;
    minute = theMinute;
    second = theSecond;
}

int Time::getHour() const {
    return hour;
}

int Time::getMinute() const {
    return minute;
}

int Time::getSecond() const {
    return second;
}

bool IsEarlierThan(const Time& t1, const Time& t2){
    if (t1.getHour() < t2.getHour()) return true;
    else if (t1.getHour() == t2.getHour()){
        if (t1.getMinute() < t2.getMinute()) return true;
        else if (t1.getMinute() == t2.getMinute()){
            if(t1.getSecond() < t2.getSecond()) return true;
        }
    } 
    return false;
}
```

The vector declaration is not correct, so my question would be how would I add these times (including hour, minute, and second) as separate vector values and compare them to each other (eg is 17:23:56 earlier than 19:49:50).

The IsEarlierThan function works, though I am unsure of how to implement it with a vector.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is this for a class assignment? Because if not, you're needlessly reinventing the wheel, where [`<chrono>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) or [`<boost/datetime>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/date_time.html) would be far more elegant choices for Time Representation.

Comment: Yes, it is. Hence, why I also have to stick to not using C++ 11

Answer (score 2):

Vector declaration is correct, vector *construction* is incorrect.
`std::vector` does not have a constructor which accepts two arguments of vector's element type.

If you want to initialize `vector` with the values from your code - change this line to:

```
std::vector<Time> times {Time(4,5,4), Time(3,5,4)};
```

See [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) for detailed explanation how it works under the hood.

**Edit:**

For earlier than C++11 stardard - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236197/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-initialize-a-stdvector-with-hardcoded-elements).

Or if you don't care about this explicitly to be *a single-statement* assingment - just use `push_back`:

```
std::vector<Time> times;      // create an empty vector
times.push_back(Time(4,5,4)); // append element to vector
times.push_back(Time(3,5,3));
```

Comment: Using this, my compiler gives me this warning ` warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11` - can I only do this with C++ 11?

Comment: @Mariankka Yes, list-initialization is supported only since C++11. If you have no specific reason to stick to earlier standards - I suggest to move to modern version. At this moment C++11 is 'current' and default in most of applications.
Nevetheless, if you have to do it oldschool - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236197/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-initialize-a-stdvector-with-hardcoded-elements) post. Basically you have a choise - either to do a trick with arrays or use `boost::assign` or write your own impl of something `boost::assign`-like.

Comment: My instructor requested us to use the older version of C++ for compatibility reasons...Looking at the link you provided, I wonder if there is a way to do this with push_back?

Comment: @Mariankka of course. just contruct the vector with default constructor and then `push_back`.

Comment: I tried this but compiler doesn't agree. Any ideas? `std::vector<Time> times (Time t1, Time t2);
  times.push_back(Time t1(3, 4, 5));
  times.push_back(Time t2(4, 4, 5));`

Comment: @Mariankka edited an answer. you should use *default* constructor - constructor with no arguments - to create an empty `vector`.

Comment: Assuming you mean `std::vector<Time> times;`, I get an error saying expected primary-expression before ‘t1 (same thing for t2)’, so I assume I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147489/discussion-between-k-v-and-mariankka).