# How to resolve or fix this error in (dev cpp ) [Error] in C++98 'v' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'

Tags: c++, vector, c++98

error in this line when create vector program in cpp program
and how to resolve in dev cpp editor

```
vector<int> v={12,24,56,45,32,76};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the easiest way to initialize a std::vector with hardcoded elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236197/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-initialize-a-stdvector-with-hardcoded-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a an array first that you then use with the `vector` constructor that takes iterators.

Example:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T, size_t N>
size_t size(const T(&)[N]) {
    return N;
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {12,24,56,45,32,76};

    std::vector<int> v(arr, arr+size(arr));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got this Issue & has been fixed.

In Devc++ ,

Go to

Tool > Compiler Options > Settings > Code Generation

& Set "Language Standard" to "ISO C++11"

No need any other changes.[See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq4bd.png)